# Odd closed neighborhood

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a given graph. prove that you can color some vertices of $G$ red, so that each vertex has odd red vertices in its closed neighborhood.

closed neighbor hood of a vertex $u$, is union of the set of all vertices adjacent to $u$ and the set:$\{u\}$ itself.

the question in other words is: find a induced sub-graph ,$S$, of a given graph $G$, which all vertices in $S$ is of even degree and all vertices in $V(G)\setminus S$ has odd number of neighbors in $S$.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED: I have tried induction on the number of vertices of $G$ so far, but it didn't work.

There is a theorem in [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=ButlynVk25MC&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=partition%20into%20even%20subgraph&source=bl&ots=u5inHvSQ_M&sig=rYh8jFM33GmDt0vxVEGJ8naqKwM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMI9prZwOrayAIVBjkaCh3a6Q5m#v=onepage&q=partition%20into%20even%20subgraph&f=false) book: The vertex set of every graph can be partitioned into two sets that induce even sub-graphs. I tried same kind of induction that is used to prove this theorem. Choose a vertex $v$ of odd degree and toggle pairs of vertices adjacent to $v$, then omit $v$ from vertex set of graph $G$. by induction hypothesis we can color a set of vertices so that every vertex has odd colored vertices in its closed neighborhood. now if vertex $v$ has odd number of red vertex adjacent to it, do not color $v$ other wise color $v$. by doing this all vertices has odd number of red vertices in their closed neighborhood except those are adjacent to $v$ and aren't colored red. I couldn't do much better for those vertices which after induction may have problems!

Comment: please make sure, that you work out what is your question and what is just information. Also please add what you've tried so far...

Comment: the question in other words is: find a induced sub-graph ,S, of a given graph G, which all vertices in S is of even degree and all vertices in V(G)\S has odd number of neighbors in S.
I have tried induction on |V(G)| but it doesn't work so much.

Comment: I suggest that you add this to your question body - it is much more likely that people answer your question if it is clear what is asked and what you've tried. Welcome on math.SE!

Comment: I tried to solve this but it does not seem as easy as the problem you refer to.  If you ever find the solution can you post it here ?  I'm interested.

Comment: Fortunately I could solve it 2 days ago... I will post a few tips in hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last I found the solution!

I want to generalize the problem.
First I define open vertex and close vertex.

We call a vertex "open" if it has *even* number of red vertices in its *open neighborhood*, we call a vertex "close" if it has *odd* number of red vertices in its *closed neighborhood*.

The generalized problem is: given a graph $G$ and a sequence $a(i)$ of size $|V(G)|$  of entries {*close, open*}. prove that you can color some vertices red so for each $i$ if $a(i)$ is open then $v_{i}$ is open vertex and it is closed otherwise.

(Actually in main problem, the sequence is $a(i)$=*close* for each i.)

now use induction on $|V(G)|$. suppose in sequence $a$ all entries are open, then if you color no vertex obviously all vertices will be open.

so there will be a close entry in sequence $a$. without loss of generality name it $v_{1}$.
Let U={all vertices adjacent to $v_{1}$}. remove $v_{1}$ from $G$ and toggle all edges in U. (I mean for each pair $x$ and $y$ in $U$ if $xy$ was in $E(G)$ remove this edge and other wise add new edge $xy$). also in sequence $a$, if $v_{i}$ is in $U$ then toggle $a(i)$ from close to open and open to close.
use induction hypothesis in new graph. by a few observation you can finish the solution.

Answer (score -1):

See under the term : odd-domination sets. Sutner proved it first in 1988 and I gave a linear algebraic proof in 1996.